# How do I collect the csv datasets as a matrix instead of a tuple?

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv, deep-learning

```
#helper libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#loading the data
import os
train_dataset = pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/mnist_train_small.csv")
test_dataset = pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/mnist_test.csv")

# each image is mapped to a label so  (a number from 1 to 10) so for ease of use the labels have been given class names
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Pair of Trouser', 'Pull over', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle Boot']

#exploring the data
train_dataset.shape()
test_dataset.shape()
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> 1 #exploring hte data
> 2 """we need to know the dimensions of our data so that we know how best to concatenate or give it any similar process"""
> ----> 3 train_dataset.shape()
> 4 test_dataset.shape()

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Shape` is not a callable function. Just use as below instead of `shape()` and you will get its dimensions

```
train_dataset.shape
test_dataset.shape
```